# How do you use 'find' to update ownership of all directories, files, and symbolic links in a folder?

Tags: files, permissions, find

I'm trying to update the ownership of everything in a directory tree from me to root. I'm using `find` to do it a little more carefully than a recursive `chown`.

Here are the commands I use to change ownership of all files and directories in my tree:

```
cd /opt/mydir
# Update files
sudo find . -type f -execdir chown root:root "{}" +
# Update directories
sudo find . -type d -execdir chown root:root "{}" +
```

These work fine for all files and directories.

But I noticed there are symbolic links in `/opt/mydir` that point to files somewhere in the same directory tree, that I still retain ownership of.

For example:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 civfan civfan      6 Jul 18  2013 halt -> reboot
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    14832 Jun 25  2013 reboot
```

This looks wrong and seems likely to cause me permission problems later if I don't fix it now.

How do I change ownership of all symbolic link files, too?

Comment: I would suggest making a small addition to the line changing ownership of the directories to make it recursive within those: `sudo find . -type d -execdir chown -R root:root "{}" +`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ownership of symbolic links don't matter.  Its the referenced entitiy which does.

That said, use `find -l` to discover symbolic links in a directory tree.

Use `chown -h` and/or `chmod -h` to operate on the symbolic link.

```
find . -type l -exec chown -h root:root {} +
```

Comment: Good info about the ownership of the symbolic link not mattering. I deleted my answer that didn't have that info in favor of this.